# How can you capture multiple possible inputs for a capture group with regex

Tags: regex, logstash, grok

Just to get out in the beginning, if there is a better way of doing this please let me know!

I am trying to parse out fields of an event log that capture agent data using regex and have ran into the issue where my current expression breaks when a particular field has more than one input. An example of the field:

```
cs1=123.abc.com (ip: 10.1.1.1, component_id: x)
```

In the example above, the expression works. Below is an example of when it breaks:

```
cs1=123.abc.com (ip: 10.1.1.2, component_id: x), 456.abc.com (ip: 10.1.1.3, component_id: y)
```

The amount of additional agents can vary to 5+, and I can't seem to find a feasible way to capture the added data without the capture group being overwritten to the last match.

For reference, my original expression for this field was:

```
cs1=(?'cs1'[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]*)\s\(ip:\s(?'IP'[0-9.]*),\scomponent_id:\s(?'ComponentID'[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]*)\)
```

Also to note, I'm using this in a Grok filter for logstash in case that affects any environmental considerations.

In trying to keep the expression scalable to not only work with one agent referenced in the log but also 5+, I've tried to work with positive lookahead groups and had limited success but they break the rest of my expression and don't capture just match for me. I'm sure I'm using them wrong but I'm having trouble understanding the logic they use. The expression that had limited success for me, for reference:

```
(?=(?:(?>\=|\s)(?'Agent'[\w.]+)(?>\s|\=)))
```

**I'm by no means a regex expert so apologies if that is sloppy or I'm missing something here.**

Comment: Personally I wouldn't do this using grok, but instead use a ruby filter and String.scan

Comment: Not sure if understanding it as you meant, how about e.g. [something like this demo?](https://regex101.com/r/qSPDN2/1)

Comment: @bobblebubble while that works just with the field, the problem is it breaks when applied to the entire log, for [example](https://regex101.com/r/7yeV9G/1)

Comment: @Teezuz I see, you would need to make all substring that can occur before *optional* like in [this update](https://regex101.com/r/ITunWj/1) but I guess parts of the pattern can be optional too? So this will get an almost impossible task.